# How to remove results from search?

Tags: xml, search, google-search-api

We have a website that uses google custom search api (found here:https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en ) for searching pages found in our website. The problem is some pages have been removed but still show up in the search. How can I remove them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that most of the pages found were referenced in a sitemap.xml page crawled by google. I was able to debug this issue using Google webmaster tools (In case anyone else has this same issue).Most of the results were removed. There are still some results that may contain the searched keywords but this is a good enough solution.